# Enable Cowboy error logs

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I tired to test a cowboy websocket handler, I compiled and run my application with:

```
make run
```

For Now I can just see my outputs (like io:format ...) but I can't see cowboy error/warning logs.

How can I enable error logging in cowboy ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look into the latest cowboy source code and it uses [error_logger](http://erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html).

Thus, you could use the [sasl application](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html) because it includes error_logger event handlers.

By configuring the sasl application (in the sys.config for instance) you control how, when and where are the logs are written.